# Why Cypress test is not able to trigger a script in a child window?

Tags: cypress

I have a pop up window containing a script in its head. And this script should be triggered by click on the window button. But after click on this button the script does not run. Could you suggest the reason?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Click on a button in the main window.
2. Child window containing a simple form is open.
3. Move to the child window, fill in the form fields and click on submit button.

**Expected result:** The click triggers a script located in the child window head. The script process the form and submit it.

**Actual result:** an error arises: "submitMyForm is not defined" (reference: submitMyForm() is a method containing in the script mentioned above).
So the problem is that the child window form fields can be populated and form button can be clicked but the script bounded to the button by means of the link `<a href="javascript:submitMyForm();">` does not work as the function submitMyForm() is not found. Obviously the reason of the test failure is stubbing the child window which is performed to prevent having 2 windows at the same time. After this the child window is opening in the same browser tab as Cypress is not able to work with 2 windows open in the same time. But in this case the script stops working neither from the test nor by performing the click manually.

Here is a code snippet from the Cypress test:

```js
const pop_url = `/dir1/dir2/file.php?id=${sectionId}`; // Here is a new window URL
cy.window().then( win => {
  const stub = cy.stub(win, 'open').as('windowopen');
  newSurveySectionListObj.AddNewBtnClick();  // Triggers form opening in the new window
  cy.get('@windowopen').should('be.called.with', pop_url);
  cy.window().then( $win => {
    $win.location.href = pop_url
    newSurveySectionListObj.typeDropdownSelect('Matrix'); // works fine
    newSurveySectionListObj.modalDescriptionFldType('Cypress test string'); // works fine
    newSurveySectionListObj.responseTypeDropdownSelect('Checkbox'); // works fine
    cy.get('a[href="javascript:submitMyForm();"]').click(); // Does not work despite the button is clicked. An error "submitMyForm is                                                             // not defined" arises
   });
});
```

Comment: See [Cypress using child window](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-using-child-window/) for info on how to change the Cypress context to the child window. Set `cy.state('document')` and `cy.state('window')` and you won't be afouling any more.

Answer (score 0):

You are going beyond what Cypress is capable of/designed for.

I would question why you are using a separate window in your app? You will run afoul of pop-up blockers that will prevent the new window being opened anyway. A percentage of users won't be able to work it out.

There are 2 approaches to this:

1. Use a modal dialog to achieve this (not great on mobile)
2. Use another route/page to display your form, return to the prev page when done

These have the advantage that they won't break with pop-up blockers, and your Cypress tests will work, as they are still in the same window.